# Apply design Patterns to android with firebase application

Tags: android, design-patterns, firebase

I want to apply design pattern to my application.
I think to divide it by this categories:
[image: My code separation]

Where:

1. LoginListener : implements the listener for the activity
2. LoginNetwork : is the class where i want to execute the firebase code
3. LoginNetworkListener : is the class where i want to insert the code for the firebase listener
4. LoginLogic : is the class where i insert the code for initialize the googleSignIn for my application ( and the request permission )
5. LoginController : there isn't code here
6. LoginSignleton : is Singleton for all data necessary between the other Login classes.

This is my code:
LoginActivity:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "Login Activity";
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9000;

    private Button continueNoLogin;
    private SignInButton googleLogin;

    private LoginNetwork loginNetwork;
    private LoginSingleton loginSingleton;
    private LoginLogic loginLogic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        continueNoLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_unregistered);
        googleLogin = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.login_registered_google);
        loginNetwork = new LoginNetwork();
        loginSingleton = LoginSingleton.getInstance();
        loginLogic = new LoginLogic(this,this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LoginListener loginListener = new LoginListener();
        continueNoLogin.setOnClickListener(loginListener);
        googleLogin.setOnClickListener(loginListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG,"OnActivityResult");
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Log.d(TAG,"RC_SIGN_IN");
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG,"google signin successfull");
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"SignInWithGoogle Failed " + result.getStatus());
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately

            }
        }
    }


    private class LoginListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.login_unregistered:

                    break;
                case R.id.login_registered_google:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Ho ricevuto l'intent");
                    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(LoginSingleton.getInstance().getGoogleApiClient());
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

LoginSingleton:

```
public class LoginSingleton {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

    private static LoginSingleton ourInstance = new LoginSingleton();

    public static LoginSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private LoginSingleton() {
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        this.googleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
        return googleApiClient;
    }

    public void setGoogleSignInOptions(GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions) {
        this.googleSignInOptions = googleSignInOptions;
    }

    public GoogleSignInOptions getGoogleSignInOptions() {
        return googleSignInOptions;
    }
}
```

LoginNetwork:

```
public class LoginNetwork  {

    private final static String TAG = "LoginNetwork";

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    public LoginNetwork(){

        // Init FirebaseAuth
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // generate listener
        LoginNetworkListener loginNetworkListener = new LoginNetworkListener();

        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(loginNetworkListener);

    }

    private class LoginNetworkListener implements FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener{

        private final static String TAG = "LoginNetworkListener";

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                Log.d(TAG,firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().toString()+"is signedIn");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"User is signedOut");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

LoginLogic:

```
public class LoginLogic {

    private final static String TAG = "LoginLogic";

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;

    public LoginLogic(Context context, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity){

        LoginListener loginListener = new LoginListener();
        /*
        * Configure Google Signin
        */
        LoginSingleton.getInstance().setGoogleSignInOptions(new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("571158992107-7bifs7qrivnqpkk77gmmoko9rkg73c0d.apps.googleusercontent.com").requestEmail().build());

        LoginSingleton.getInstance().setGoogleApiClient(
            new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).
                    enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity,new LoginConnectionFailed()).
                    build());
    }
}
```

When i start the application it give me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    Process: it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb, PID: 24354                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb/it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb.loginPack.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb.loginPack.LoginNetwork.<init>(LoginNetwork.java:19)
at it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb.loginPack.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:35)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6304)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Where:

```
LoginNetwork.java:19 is -> firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

and

```
LoginActivity.java:35 is -> loginNetwork = new LoginNetwork();
```

If I comment this part of LoginActivity:

```
loginNetwork = new LoginNetwork();
```

and after launch the app it doesn't work anyway. It give me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb, PID: 3917
java.lang.InstantiationError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqz
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.enableAutoManage(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.enableAutoManage(Unknown Source)
at it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb.loginPack.LoginLogic.<init>(LoginLogic.java:32)
at it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.dafb.loginPack.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6304)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Where:
LoginLogic.java:32 is:

```
LoginSingleton.getInstance().setGoogleApiClient(new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity).enableAutoManage(activity,new LoginConnectionFailed()).build());
```

I don't understand the where is the error. Please help me.
Thanks a lot!

I want to create this "class" diagram:
[image: MVC modified]
But this class diagram is for all application where for Persistent Data I want to create a background Service wich update del SQLLite Database in my application from the Firebase application. Or any other solution to have offline firebase database to use app offline.

Comment: `LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity();` I'm not sure if that's the problem, but you shouldn't create Activity classes like that

Comment: I know, but i don't now the metod to call startactvity for result from Loginistener Class. Do you have suggestion?

Comment: Move the listeners class inside the activity. No reason to have it be a new class file entirely

Comment: I refactoring in this way: LoginNetworkListener is now a class of LoginNetwork and the same LoginListener.

Comment: Do you have to give a Context and an activity to the login logic? An activity is a Context already

Comment: Please can you be more clear?

Comment: You only should need `LoginLogic(Context context)`. In any case, I'm not sure what "design pattern" you are trying to follow here, but I'd recommend getting it to work without any patterns, then refactor

Comment: Model Online is the Firebase, Model ( class that describe the tipe of data I retrieve from Firebase Database ) is on the smartphone.

Comment: Android naturally forces you into a Model View Controller pattern. Listeners and Singletons aren't really necessary to achieve that. Your error very clearly says `Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first`, but you haven't done that

Comment: If I do the error not change!

Comment: Are you doing it as one of the first things in LoginActivity?

Comment: Yes after setContentView().